# Does a two-dimensional array of character pointers need to be terminated by two null?

Tags: c++

The other day, I was reading a book where I found this code:

```
char *words[][40] = {"Goat", "A herbivore",
                     "Dog", "An omnivore",
                     "Fox", "A carnivore",
                     "Bear", "An omnivore"
                     "", ""};
```

And the book said, "notice, the list must be terminated by two nulls". But when I compiled this code without the nulls, it compiled and worked just as desired. Please explain if the nulls are of any use. I am quite new to C(++), so please elaborate.

Comment: @Andreas The Complete Reference C++ by Herbert Schildt

Comment: @Rage I'm not familiar with this particular book, but Schildt has a very poor reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `"", ""` is used as sentinel values, to indicate the end of the array as the dimension of the array is not specified and is deduced from the initializer. Note those are not `NULL`s, but empty strings. A loop that iterates over this array would use `strlen(words[i])` to know it is accessing the last element in the array and prevent accessing beyond the bounds of the array.

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; strlen(words[i]); i++)
{
}
```

Instead of using empty strings `NULL` could have been used and avoid the `strlen()` call to detect the last element in the array:

```
const char *words[] = {"Goat", "A herbivore",
                       "Dog", "An omnivore",
                       "Fox", "A carnivore",
                       "Bear", "An omnivore",
                       NULL};


for (int i = 0; words[i]; i++)
{
}
```

---

It is possible to determine the number of elements in `words`, even though the dimension is not explicity stated using `sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0])` but if the array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array and the calculation is no longer correct and either a sentinel value must exist in the array or number of elements in the array must be supplied to the function.

Comment: But why do we need two? And by this approach does it mean the programmer will keep a check to loop through the array till `""` is reached?

Comment: @SuvP, yes the programmer needs to detect the last element in the array. Have updated answer.

Comment: Yes i was wondering if it was some standard :P  Confusion cleared!

Comment: @SuvP, note two `""` are not required. The intent of the `words` array appears to be a mapping. I guess the programmer liked the consistency of `name-value` and use `""-""` but one `""` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The list does not have to be be terminated by two nulls for technical reasons.

But if your code does not know the length of list, you can iterate through it until it is terminated by the null elements.

Comment: So even One null would have served the purpose? Just like keeping something like "`THE_END`" at the end of the list? Basically, its just for the programmer to loop correctly(loop until you reach `""` or "`THE_END`") ?

Comment: Using "THE_ENDE" wouldn't be a good idea as this could be a valid entry in the table. Usually people simple use a NULL.
The list looks like two consecutive are belonging together, so everbody would be expect the list to have a even number of entries. So it's better to putt two NULL entries at the end.

Comment: We can't say what is needed, because the given code won't even compile.  (But there's no case where two null's are needed.  Regardless of what is meant by a null.)

Comment: I can compile the code without problems. If the example has any pratical usage is debatable.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted won't compile.  Are you sure you copied it
exactly from the book?

If we add the obvious missing comma, we end up with the
equivalent of

```
char* words[1][40] = 
{
    "Goat"
    "A herbivore",
    "Dog"
    "An omnivore",
    "Fox"
    "A carnivore",
    "Bear"
    "An omnivore",
    "",
    "",
    NULL,
    //  this last line repeated 30 times...
};
```

I doubt that that is what was intended either.  (It results in
a list which is terminated by 30 nulls, not just 2.)

I suspect what was meant was without the `*` as well:

```
char words[][2][40] =
{
    "Goat", "A herbivore",
    "Dog", "An omnivore",
    "Fox", "A carnivore",
    "Bear", "An omnivore",
    "", ""
};
```

This results in an array[10] of array[40] of `char`.  Of course,
it would be much better to indicate this in clear:

```
char words[][2][40] =
{
    { "Goat", "A herbivore" },
    { "Dog" , "An omnivore" },
    { "Fox" , "A carnivore" },
    { "Bear", "An omnivore" },
    { ""    , ""            },
};
```

There's still the issue as to what is meant by "null".  If it is
a null pointer, then there aren't (and cannot be) any in this
version, because there are no pointers.  If it is a nul
character (`'\0'`), there are 10, one for each string.  If it is
an empty string, then the author is using a most unusual and
confusing terminology; if he means empty string, he should say
empty string.

As two what is needed: I suppose that the intent is to use
a sentinal.  The usual way of writing this (in C or in C++)
*would* be to use pointers, and write something like:

```
char const* const words[][2] =
{
    { "Goat", "A herbivore" },
    { "Dog" , "An omnivore" },
    { "Fox" , "A carnivore" },
    { "Bear", "An omnivore" },
    { NULL  , NULL          }
};
```

In this case, I probably would use two nulls, but the last line
initializing the array can be `{}`, `{ NULL }`, or `{ NULL, NULL
}`; they will all result in the same thing for the compiler.

Even with the non-pointer versions, *one* empty string is
sufficient.  The compiler will fill out all additional values
with empty strings as well.

Finally, as to why you need the null pointers or empty strings:
in C, they were frequently used as a sentinal: you would loop
until you encountered one:

```
for ( char const* const (*p)[2] = words; (*p)[0] != NULL; ++ p ) {
    std::cout << (*p)[0] << " - " << (*p)[1] << std::endl;
}
```

In C++, you'ld almost never use the sentinal, because you could
write something like:

```
for ( char const* const (*p)[2] = begin( words );
        p != end( words );
        ++ p ) {
    std::cout << (*p)[0] << " - " << (*p)[1] << std::endl;
}
```

In C++11, that would be `std::begin` and `std::end`, but of
course, before C++11, everyone had an implementation of them in
their personal toolkit.  In C++11, you could also use `auto`:

```
for ( auto p = begin( words ); p != end( words ); ++ p ) {
    std::cout << (*p)[0] << " - " << (*p)[1] << std::endl;
}
```

I'm not sure if this buys us much, however; you still need to be
aware of the complicated type when you use it.  (`auto` does buy
a lot when you have types that are fundamentally simple to use,
but which are difficult to spell out, like iterators.)

Finally, of course, neither in C nor in C++ would anyone use
a two dimensional array for this.  We'd define a struct:

```
struct Mapping
{
    char const* animalName;
    char const* eatingType;
};

Mapping const map[] = 
{
    { "Goat", "A herbivore" },
    { "Dog" , "An omnivore" },
    { "Fox" , "A carnivore" },
    { "Bear", "An omnivore" },
    { NULL  , NULL          }
};

for ( Mapping const* p = map; p->animalName != NULL; ++ p ) {
    //  ...
}
```

(With `begin` and `end` in C++, of course, instead of the
sentinal.)

And by the way: unless you've horribly misquoted the book, throw
it away.  The author obviously doesn't know either C nor C++.